# jQuery - Remove DIVs based on class name

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to remove all DIVs on a page via jQuery -- keeping their content intact -- which have this pattern to them?

```
<div class="ExternalClass85AC900AB26A481DBDC8ADAE7A02F039">....</div>
```

Note that the DIVs follow this pattern:

- class name will always start with `ExternalClass` but will be followed by another value, never the same,
- and the DIV has **no other attributes but `class`**. (This is on SharePoint)

Thanks.

Comment: Please note that the DIV should have **only** the class attribute and no other attributes. The solutions provided all are great, but can someone provide a addition for this issue?

Comment: Made me laugh that this was the first result I've searched for and, even though neither my search or your OP mentions it, I'm fully aware we're probably both having this issue because of SharePoint? +1 for good question.

Comment: EDIT: Didn't notice your 'This is on SharePoint' at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and the [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method:

```
$('[class^="ExternalClass"]').filter(function() { 
  return this.attributes.length === 1; 
}). replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: @dfsq A good point, in the previous incarnation it was useful to avoid creating a jQuery object again, but since `replaceWith` works on all matched elements the `each` call was unnecessary.

Comment: One problem with all these answers: I need to remove the DIVs that have **only** the class attribute and no other attributes on them.

Comment: Thanks, Rich. Why does the `return this.attributes.length === 1;` have a return on it? Thanks again :)

Comment: @Alex This will filter the set of matched elements to this that have only one attribute (in this case guaranteed to be the class attribute) - it returns true if this is the case, false otherwise. Have a look at the jQuery Filter method for more info.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[class^="ExternalClass"]').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, dfsq. Please see my comment to the question and the second bullet of the requirements: the DIV should have only the class attribute and no other attributes. All the answers thus far ignore this. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Get the inner html from the div.
Get the parent or previous tag, to paste the content into or after you've removed the div.
Jquery may have a replace function, not sure, which would be easier.

Should be able to use .remove() to get rid of the div.

$("[class$='ExternalClass']").remove();
might be id*= i forget which one.

Revised:
http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: They have the function above, just found it, looks like it will work.

Comment: That selects an ID, not a class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-write the HTML.

`$("div [class^=ExternalClass]")` will select the elements.

Grab the innerHTML, append it after the element, then remove the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using attribute starts with selector `^=`.

```
$('div[class^="ExternalClass"]').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $text = ""; 
$.each($("div"), function(){
    $text = $text + this.html();
});
document.write($text);
```

Answer (score 1):

sample HTML:

```
<div class="ExternalClass85AC900AB26A481DBDC8ADAE7A02F039">foo</div>
<div class="ExternalClass85AC900AB26A481DBDC8ADAE7A02sdfsdsdfF039">bar</div>
```

sample Jquery:

```
$('div[class^="ExternalClass"]').each(function() {
  $(this).contents().unwrap();
});
```

Output:

```
foo bar
```

(wihtout divs)

heres the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6hbhL/

Answer (score 1):

My code:

```
function unrichText(texto) {
  var n = texto.indexOf("\">"); //Finding end of "<div&nbsp;class="ExternalClass...">
  var sub = texto.substring(0, n+2); //Adding first char and last two (">)
  var tmp = texto.replace(sub, ""); //Removing it
  tmp = replaceAll(tmp, "</div>", ""); //Removing last "div"
  tmp = replaceAll(tmp, "<p>", ""); //Removing other stuff
  tmp = replaceAll(tmp, "</p>", "");
  tmp = replaceAll(tmp, "&#160;", "");
  return (tmp);
}

function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @WalterDiBiase. Good job! Very nice approach :) And welcome to StackOverflow!